# Office 2016 beta on Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have coworkers that are using many features that are in office 2013, 2016 for Windows,  and I want to get office 2016 for Mac. I don't have office 365, I just want the local version.

How can I get it?

Comment: To whomever the downvoter is: why the downvote? I asked the question in chat, and was told to ask it on the main site

Comment: They probably downvoted because we're technically not allowed to ask questions about beta software that's under NDAs. Public betas are a real gray area.

Comment: Actually open betas are generally on topic. Ones with NDA have been considered problematic, but this is on topic IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office 2016 for Mac has a stable release available for Office 365 subscribers. It'll be available as a standalone purchase at some unspecified date in September. Until then, it looks like Microsoft has taken their beta down. What you could do is wait as long as you can bear to live without Office and then sign up for a [free trial of Office 365](https://products.office.com/en-us/try-office-365-personal), and then unsubscribe and buy Office 2016 once it comes out in September.

Comment: And that works for macs also?

Comment: Wait, no, that link is for Windows. I think Microsoft took their beta down. Sorry.

Comment: The mac link is here https://products.office.com/en-us/mac/microsoft-office-for-mac and says "Office 2016 for Mac is now available with Office 365.
One-time purchase coming in September."

Comment: The preview is only for 8 days